# Complete protection against mail-injection

Tags: php, security, email, spam-prevention

Suppose we're sending trivial feedback and going to make these fields dynamic:

- sender name
- sender e-mail
- subject
- message body

would be this PHP code enough to protect us from all kinds of mail-injections?

```
  //sanitizing email address
if ($email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  //encoding subj according to RFC and thus protecting it from all kinds of injections
  $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['subject'])."?=";
  //encoding name for same reasons, and using sanitized email
  $from    = "From: =?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['name'])."?= <$email>\r\n";
  //protecting body as it mentioned in http://php.net/mail
  $message = str_replace("\n.", "\n .", $_POST['text']);
  mail('me@example.com',$subject,$message,$from);
}
```

at the moment I am playing with names like `"some@email.com, other@email.com,"` but it seems that all available mail clients handling it correctly

Comment: With my rather limited understanding, I think this is enough :)

Comment: funny - I'm sure you said a few days ago that injecting a '.' on its own would 'never work'....

Comment: well I am still learning, like we all do

Comment: Indeed. I _think_ you downvoted me for suggesting that you were wrong...

Comment: thanks for correcting that - see also http://spotthevuln.com/2011/01/sleep-smtp-command-injection/

Answer (score 2):

> would be this PHP code enough to protect us from all kinds of mail-injections?

It looks pretty comprehensive, just as long as your email client supports the [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) encoding method you're using in the headers.  (Some webmail clients don't recognize the encoding.)

My only recommendation, other than not using `mail()` to begin with, would be considering [is_email](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/) rather than the built-in filter.  The built-in fails a number of edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if the filter complies with rfc that specify that the local part cant contain anything if it is surrounded by " or whatever character some address like "foo\r\nTo: poor-guy@dom.tld\r\nTo: dummy"@foo.tld will give you headers like :

```
Subject: foo
To: poor-guy@dom.tld
To: dummy"@foo.tld
```

quite bad ...

Comment: so, you gonna say that `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` will allow that?